# How can set "wait time" in CZML?

Tags: cesiumjs, czml

I have some position & time values describing movement of some vehicle. But in some time intervals vehicle wait in some position. I cant figure out how can i set waiting time.?

In the example data provided below :  position values corresponding to 40 and 50 are same = (4, 4 ,0) That means vehicle wait 10 second in that position. But it doesn't work because of interpolation.

Ex :

```
"position":{
      "interpolationAlgorithm":"LAGRANGE",
      "interpolationDegree":1,
      "epoch":"2012-08-04T16:00:00Z",
      "cartesian": [
        0.0,  0, 0, 0,
        10.0, 1 ,1 ,0,
        20.0, 2, 2, 0,
        30.0, 3, 3, 0,
        40.0, 4, 4, 0,
        50.0, 4, 4, 0
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found that we can use "interval" property. Such that :

```
"position" : [
        {
            "interval": "2018-08-07T23:50:00Z/2018-08-08T00:09:00Z",
            "cartographicDegrees" : [
                "2018-08-07T23:50:00Z", 39.8495,43.3802,0,
                "2018-08-08T00:00:00Z", 39.8734,43.4129,0,
                "2018-08-08T00:09:00Z", 39.8048,43.4324,0
            ],

            "interpolationAlgorithm": "LAGRANGE",
            "interpolationDegree": 5
        },

        {
            "interval": "2018-08-08T00:09:00Z/2018-08-08T00:11:00Z",
            "cartographicDegrees" : [39.8048,43.4324,0]
        }, 
...
```